# ACL implementation with Codeigniter / Ion Auth

Tags: authentication, codeigniter, acl

Is there any ACL implementation written for Ion Auth, or that would be easily integrated with Ion Auth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [is_group()](http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/#is_group) to check the user's group and take appropriate action, but beyond that there currently is no access control or user based permissions built into Ion Auth, and I'm not aware of any that would be easier to integrate into Ion Auth than another system - but you can certainly use Ion Auth as a starting point to building your own.

Comment: That's really what I've been doing - just that a more robust ACL could clean up the code a little bit more - I'm sure if I put my thinking cap on I could do that as well ;)

Answer (score 3):

Check out Ion Auth v2, taken some big steps towards extendability:

http://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth/tree/2

Comment: edmunds - can you point me at the acl implementation in this code?

Comment: I'm interested too, does Ion Auth V2 support ACL out of the box ?

Comment: Is it stable enough to use?

Answer (score 1):

There currently is none. the is_group() function is a start, but users can only belong to 1 group at the moment. Permission inheritance / member of multiple groups is not yet included in the roadmap to my knowledge.

Head over to https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth and check out the latest. Fork it! And contribute your changes to the community....

Answer (score 0):

weblogics created this type of system based on Ion Auth as an extension.

Hope this helps or for a jump start in getting this into Ion Auth so far its been working great but not much documenations on use

[Codeigniter-Ion-Auth-ACL](https://github.com/weblogics/Codeigniter-Ion-Auth-ACL)